# Alias name not woking for order by cluase - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-5.7

I have query which looks like this :

```
SELECT 
  x.col1, x.col2l
FROM (
    SELECT
      col1,
      col2
  FROM tab1) x
where x.col2 = 'someval'
ORDER BY x.col1 ASC
```

Its working on my development machine (Mysql 5.6) , but in production (Mysql 5.7.18) it is throwing an error like **unknown column x.col1**. Is this operation is not comatible with version 5.7.18. If i remove alias it is giving me the result.

This is a sql string and will be executed using prepare statement.

Comment: The sub query doesn't seem to have any point.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Give complete executable code & exact output. (Is `x.col2l` a typo?)

Comment: If you removed the table alias, then MySQL should return a syntax error saying that derived tables should all have aliases.